# Need ideas to change a key's name of JSON Object on RUBY

Tags: ruby, json, hash, key

i am finding a method to change a key's name of json object that is a hash on ruby like below

source

```
{ "a" => "b", "b" => "bb" }
```

result

```
{ "c" => "b", "b" => "bb" }
```

got a nice idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603567/change-all-key-names-of-json-object-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

If you need this functionality frequently, you can extend the Ruby Hash class.

Implementation would vary from ruby version to version, but roughly something like this:

```
class Hash
  module ClassMethods
    def self.replace_key(old_key, new_key)
     self[new_key] = self[old_key]
     self.delete(old_key)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, creating a new key,value pair in the Hash using the new key and old value. Then deleting the original pair.

*Note: Operations like this on large hashes are inadvisable from a performance perspective.*

Answer (score 1):

```
source = { "a" => "b", "b" => "bb", "c" => "lol" }
PATTERN = { "a" => "c", "c" => "e" }
source.inject({}) do |new_hash, (k, v)|
  key = PATTERN[k] || k
  new_hash[key] = v
  new_hash
end
#=> { "c" => "b", "b" => "bb", "e" => "lol" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are serializing ActiveRecord or ActiveModel object, you can overwrite `as_json` method of the class. Like so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options = { })
     super((options.select {|k,v| k.to_s != "a" }).merge("c" => options["a"]))
  end
end
```